# Java - Rounding BigDecimal value with 2 decimal place at 2 levels

Tags: java, bigdecimal

`decimalValue=10.2345` gives `10.23` after rounding using below code

```
decimalValue.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
```

I need value to be displayed as `10.24`. Found one solution to rounding at 2 levels, like first to 3 digits and then to 2 digits as given below

```
decimalValue.setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
```

Please suggest if anyone has better solution.

Comment: Why should `10.2345` round to `10.24`? Please [edit] your question to include other example numbers and how they should be rounded.

Comment: Are you thinking of `RoundingMode.CEILING` instead? Or using HALF_UP to 3 decimals, and then rounding again using HALF_UP to two decimals?

Comment: `10.2345` is less than `10.235` and thus it rounds to `10.23`. I am rather sure that it is still taught this way in elementary school. So it does not matter that `10.2345` would round to `10.235`, because that is a different rounding task.

Answer (score 2):

`RoundingMode.HALF_UP` will round up `.5` and above.

[HALF_UP](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_UP)

> Rounding mode to round towards "nearest neighbor" unless both
>   neighbors are equidistant, in which case round up. Behaves as for RoundingMode.UP if the discarded fraction is ≥ 0.5; otherwise, behaves as for RoundingMode.DOWN.

Use `RoundingMode.UP` instead

```
decimalValue.setScale(2, RoundingMode.UP)
```